# How do I add status to component versions in Snapshot In Urban code deploy Using CLI?

Tags: automation, devops-services, urbancode, udeploy, ucd

I am able to add status to snapshot saying "Snap ready for Release" using CLI.
I am wondering how do I add status to the component versions that are in Snapshot using CLI?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

you need to get versions in a snapshot and then assign status to individual versions - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS4GSP_6.2.7/com.ibm.udeploy.api.doc/topics/udclient_getsnapshotversions.html

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS4GSP_6.2.7/com.ibm.udeploy.api.doc/topics/udclient_addversionstatus.html

Comment: Yes, you might need a small groovy to parse the snapshot id and retrieve version details, and then update status for applicable version using the second cli

Comment: Thank you, I am not familiar with it, can I have the syntax please